# Every set in a sigma-algebra not measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, real-numbers

I'm studying Axler's measure theory book and there a set is said to be measurable if it belongs to a $\sigma$-algebra. A power set is always a $\sigma$-algebra, and combining these, it would seem that every set in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb R)$ is measurable, which is not true. What am i not understanding, why don't these definitions contradict each other?

Comment: A set is said measurable (with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra) if it belongs to that   $\sigma$-algebra.  Every subset of $\Bbb R$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb R)$, but not with respect to other  $\sigma$-algebras. There are subsets of $\Bbb R$ that are NOT measurable with respect to the Lebesgue  $\sigma$-algebra.  The definition of measurable set is always with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: You don't need to define a measure space to define measurable sets. It is enough to have a measurable space, that is, $(X, \Sigma)$ where $X$ is the underlying space and $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$. Measurable sets are defined with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra. Some $\sigma$-algebra are create by Carathédory construction from pre-measures, but mneasurable sets are always those sets that are in the $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The family of measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra but not all sets belonging in any $\sigma$-algebra are measurable. So to fully define a measure space we need a set $X$, a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on $X$ and a function $\mu: \mathcal{A} \to [0, \infty]$ which satisfies some properties. A set $A \subseteq X$ is called $\mu$-measurable (or simply measurable if this doesn't cause confusion) if it belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$. You can't define a measure space without clearly stating what each of these three things is.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like the only logical explanation, but i'm still quite confused, as then the sentence: "An element of S is called an S-measurable set" as phrased in the book, doesn't really make sense?

Comment: @Pueti I edited my answer. It's just a definition. We chose to call the members of this particular $\sigma$-algebra measurable.

Comment: Ok this clears a lot, thank you!

Comment: Rather than say that we chose to call the members of this particular $\sigma$-algebra measurable, which sounds like an arbitrary choice, would it be better to say that we call those sets measurable because those are the sets in the domain of the measure? Given a different measure, defined on a different $\sigma$-algebra, we would call those sets measurable (wrt that measure).

Comment: @Joe Yeah you are right. I just simplified my comment to make it clear that this is just a definition and not some other property.

Answer (score 5):

A measure space must specify three things:

- An underlying set;
- A $\sigma$-algebra of subsets which are measurable in this measure space;
- A measure (a function on this $\sigma$-algebra).

When we say "a measurable subset of the real numbers" we typically mean "a subset of the real numbers measurable with respect to the [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure)", which is one way to make these choices. Rather than say "measurable subset", we could have said "Lebesgue-measurable subset" to avoid confusion.

You can instead define a different measure on the real numbers. You could choose to use the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, and for example decide that the measure of a set is equal to the number of integers it contains. When you're working with this measure, every subset of the real numbers is measurable, but now you're not talking about the same thing as everyone else.

Comment: Ok, can you then always define define a measure, possibly a very trivial one, such that every subset of the power set of the underlying set is measurable?

Comment: Yes, you can always do that (an even more trivial measure than the one I proposed would just say that everything has measure $0$).

Comment: Ok thank you very much this makes sense now.

Comment: @Pueti, the proof that I have seen that not every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable proceeds by assuming that a given measure is translation invariant with all subsets measurable, having finite measure on the interval $[0,1)$, which is satisfied by the trivial measure (i .e. all subsets having measure zero), then shows that this is the only measure with those three properties.